# Blender won't let me ask questions.

Tags: discussion, moderation

One day, when I was horrendously frustrated, I wrote a bad word on here because someone called me retarded. Then, I got blocked, and blender won't let me ask any questions for another 24 hours. This is urgent; I'm having an issue on blender that I have to solve or else I won't be able to do what I need done.

Comment: Maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/question-limited . While you wait for your ban to be over please read [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and also read through the [help] section to learn how to use this site.

Answer (score 11):

Your auto question ban has nothing to do with you writing a "bad word" in a comment. (Although you really shouldn't do that.) It is because your questions have all been what SE calls "not well received." Which is a polite way of saying that you need to write better questions. (I sent you a message about this a week ago.) These auto bans us mods can not change, so you are stuck till tomorrow.
If this really is so pressing you could try on [blender artists](https://blenderartists.org), or [blender's discord](https://discord.gg/SSJ7Q3T), or on the [blender sub reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/).

Please do read through the info I sent you. If you continue to write unclear, low effort posts you will find yourself bumping into the auto ban again.
As a bonus good clear questions are vastly more likely to get answered.

(PS writing "urgent" and "need it done fast" are good ways to ensure you get an answer slower.)