# How can I earn the privilege to ask more than 8 questions per day?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

I just started a major blender project. I was wondering if I can earn the privilege to ask 8+ questions (whatever the current maximum is). My questions will not be like my previous ones, as I'm doing slightly more complex tasks and am taking the time to make the questions clearer.

Comment: Have in mind that Stack Exchange in general is more of a learning tool to improve your skills, not a solve-my-problems-on-demand to have your work done for you.

Answer (score 7):

There is no daily question limit here. (SO, SU, SF, and Math have a six questions per day limit.)

There is however a 50 questions in the last 30 day limit. (If someone hits that, they probably are not using google.)

Yet you are still going to bump in to the rate limit because of your history <sup>[[1]](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2455/2217) [[2]](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2465/2217)</sup> of low quality posts. Your current rate limit (auto question ban) will expire on the 28th.

You can read about all the rate limits here:
[The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/278094)

---

But no there is no privilege to unlock extra question asking abilities.  Only thing like that is users over 10k rep only see the captcha if asking more then one question in 30 seconds.